# How can I define an operator that takes a register as an argument?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, cut-copy-paste, replace, register

I'm trying to write a "Paste-over" operator. It will work like a combination of <kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd>, so it will paste the contents of a register over the text currently in the buffer. I have this so far:

```
function! PasteOver(before)
  if a:before
    call feedkeys("m`")
  endif

  call feedkeys("R")
  for i in split(@", '\zs')
    call feedkeys(i)
  endfor
  call feedkeys("\<esc>")

  if a:before
    call feedkeys("\<C-o>")
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <M-p> :<C-u>call PasteOver(0)<cr>
nnoremap <M-P> :<C-u>call PasteOver(1)<cr
```

And it works great. However, I have a dilemma. I'd like this operator to work with registers, the same way that <kbd>p</kbd> does, e.g. `"a<M-p>` will paste over from the contents of register 'a', and have this work with every register.

There's two ways I could think of to do this:

- Write a mapping for every single register. I think it goes without saying that this is a terribly inefficient and sloppy way of doing this.
- Make the register argument come *after* the operator, so `"a<M-p>` would become `<M-p>a`. This would work fine, but it makes pasting from the default register less convenient, and I prefer the first way since it feels more natural (since my fingers have already learned `"ap`

Is there a builtin way to get the register argument to an operator? I'm thinking something like `v:count`, but `v:register` instead.

Comment: Well, `:help v:register` and `:help getreg()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `v:register` to grab the name of the last register supplied
to a command, `getreg()` to grab its contents, and `<c-r>=` to insert text from a register when in
insert (or replace) mode:

```
nnoremap <m-p> R<c-r>=getreg(v:register)<cr><esc>
nnoremap <m-P> R<c-r>=getreg(v:register)<cr><esc>`[
```

You can also use `` `[ `` to jump to the beginning of the last changed text.

Comment: Wow. This solution is way simpler than mine. And it effortlessly works with counts! `+1`